# Save and restore text selection (after page reload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a web app that allows users to select and highlight text, save the selection, and reload the selection (highlight) again next time the same page is revisited. What I am currently doing is:

1. On saving selection:

   ```
   var selection = window.getSelection();
   var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
   var rootNode = range.commonAncestorContainer;
   var nodeIndex = $(div).contents().index(rootNode);

   var savedData = "("+nodeIndex+":"+range.startOffset+"/"+range.endOffset+")"; 
   //this is what being saved to the backend
   ```
2. On restoring selection:

   ```
   //database data being parsed into nodeIndex, startOffset and endOffset
   var node = $(div).contents().eq(nodeIndex);
   var range = document.createRange();
   if (node && node.length >= endOffset) {
        range.setStart(node, startOffset);
        range.setEnd(node, endOffset);
   }
   ```

The above solution works, as long as the saving and restoring order are the same (because the `nodeIndex` are retrieved in relative to each other, but this is also the cause of the problem:

**The above solution doesn't cater the case when one or more of the selections are removed.**

If previously saved selection is removed, the `nodeIndex` of other selections will become false, therefore crushing the restoring process.

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

p/s: the requirement can actually be fulfilled by saving the entire HTML of the div into the database, so I only need to retrieve the HTML of different user and display it. But this approach sounds a little incompetent to me, and would use up more space in the database. Or is this actually fine? Any thoughts?

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Comment: @njorlsaga i ended up saving the entire html string in the database. This is the most hassle free solution to me and actually makes sense.

Comment: thanks for the response, so did you grab the entire html string from the range.startOffset to the range.endOffset? And then how did you use that html string to reselect the right part on the page?

Comment: @njorlsaga sorry for the delay. There's no need to do range and offset calculations anymore if you just save the html. It'll just load the html whenever the page is revisited.

Comment: ah so you are not showing the selection in the context of the page any more you are just showing the saved html back to the user?

Comment: @njorlsaga that is correct